# How to fuse 2 JSON with same values without overlapping

Tags: javascript, json

I need a function that having passed 2 json, return 1 json that is a fusion of both but without overlap them. Here an example:

```
var json1 = { a: {x:1, y:2} , b: {x:1, y:2} }
var json2 = { a: {z:3}, c: {z:3, h:4} }
var result = magicFunctionINeed(json1, json2);
//result should be => {a:{x:1, y:2, z:3}, b: {x:1, z:2}, c: {z:3, h:4} }
```

I need the magicFunctionINeed(). I have tried without no results. 
Thanks!

Comment: These are objects. Why don't you share your own magicFunction so that we can work on where you left ?

Comment: The problem is that I have no the magic function. I need a function that return that!

Comment: Also, what if there are conflicts? For example, your first object has `a:{x:1}` and your second object has `a:{x:2}`

Comment: I other words I need the magicFunction

Comment: @musefan it should happen never in my code. I control these

Comment: @MtgKhaJeskai: We don't write magic functions for people here. We help people fix their own broken magic functions... so try to write it yourself, and if you have a specific problem then post your code and we can help you fix it

Comment: @MtgKhaJeskai: If you control them... then why you need to merge in the first place? Why not just create the desired result to start with?

Comment: Did you try lodash ? https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#merge or https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mergeWith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce` function and loop over keys of your json objects.

```js
var json1 = { a: { x: 1, y: 2 }, b: { x: 1, y: 2 } };
var json2 = { a: { z: 3 }, c: { z: 3, h: 4} };

Object.keys(json2).reduce((a, o) => {
  if (a[o]) {
    a[o] = {...a[o], ...json2[o]};
  } else {
    a[o] = json2[o];
  }

  return a;
}, json1);

console.log(json1);
```

Comment: Why didn't you just edit your first answer? (which was the same suggestion)

Comment: @musefan I had to fix something.  I think :-)

Comment: @musefan I didn't want to get a downvote, that's the reason.

Comment: @MtgKhaJeskai important: This solution modifies the object `json1`.  Take that in mind :-)

Comment: Note that `Object.assign(a[o], json2[o])` would mutate `a[o]` and so, by extension, `json1`. Consider using `a[o] = {...a[o], ...json2[o]}` instead.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha but this `a[o] = {...a[o], ...json2[o]}` will "mutate" `a[o]`from `json1`.  I think it's preference rather than a problem.  Look the used initialValue in `reduce`function.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha btw, you did downvote for what you've stated in your previous comment?

Comment: Quite the opposite. `a[o] = anything` would create a new object, and not mutate the existing. To your other question, no, I did not downvote.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I got it!

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom function using `reduce()` method and return new object. Note that this will work for only one level of nested objects and arrays.

```js
var json1 = { a: {x:1, y:2} , b: {x:1, y:2}, g: [1, 2]}
var json2 = { a: {z:3}, c: {z:3, h:4}, g: [3], r: 123}

const merge = (...args) => {
  return args.reduce(function(r, o) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function(k) {
      if (typeof o[k] == 'object' && !Array.isArray(o[k])) r[k] = Object.assign({}, r[k], o[k])
      else if (Array.isArray(o[k])) r[k] = (r[k] || []).concat(o[k])
      else r[k] = o[k]
    })
    return r;
  }, {})
}

console.log(merge(json1, json2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generic function which can take **multiple objects as parameter** and iterate each of them using `map`

```
function mergeObj()
{
    var output = {};
    Array.from( arguments ).forEach( function( json ){
       Object.keys( json ).forEach( function( key ){
           output[ key ] = output[ key ] || {};
           Object.assign( output[ key ], output[ key ], json[ key ] ); //set the new keys inside output[key]
       });
    });
    return output;
}
```

**Demo**

```js
var json1 = { a: {x:1, y:2} , b: {x:1, y:2} };
var json2 = { a: {z:3}, c: {z:3, h:4} };
function mergeObj()
{
    var output = {};
    Array.from( arguments ).forEach( function( json ){
       Object.keys( json ).forEach( function( key ){
           output[ key ] = output[ key ] || {};
           Object.assign( output[ key ], output[ key ], json[ key ] );
       });
    });
    return output;
}
console.log( mergeObj( json1, json2 ) );
```

**Note**

It only goes **one level deep**, it won't merge nested property values deeper than immediate properties of passed object.

Comment: Worth noting this goes only one level deep.

Comment: Thanks! Is true that it only works in 1 level deep but that was what I needed! Thanks you a lot!

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Yes, I have left a note. Seems OP's requirement is the same as well.